# Custom collapsible view

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to create a custom collapsible view. The code works but in `Collapsible<Content: View>` the `VStack` has strange behavior: the elements overlap when the component is closed.
To note this, try disable `clipped()` as shown in the image.

[image: overlap content]

Is it a bug or something so stupid that I am not noticing?
Thanks in advance

**FIXED CODE:**

```swift
struct Collapsible<Content: View>: View {
    var label: String
    var content: () -> Content
    init(label: String, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self.content = content
    }
    @State private var collapsed: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    self.collapsed.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text(label)
                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                        Image(systemName: self.collapsed ? "chevron.down" : "chevron.up")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
                }
            )
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            self.content()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: collapsed ? 0 : .none, alignment: .top) // <- added `alignment` here
            .clipped() // Comment to see the overlap
            .animation(.easeOut)
            .transition(.slide)
        }
    }
}

struct CollapsibleDemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Collapsible(label: "Collapsible") {
                Text("Content")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`.frame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/frame(width:height:alignment:)) modifier has a parameter alignment which defaults to `center` which results in the behaviour you're seeing: the layout bounds are set to zero height but the content is rendered vertically centered beyond the bounds (if not clipped). You can fix this by adding the alignment:

```
.frame(maxHeight: 0, alignment: .top)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! With `max Height:0` the content doesn't appear, obviously. Instead adding `alignement: .top` to `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: collapsed ? 0 : .none, alignment: .top)` solve the problem! Thanks! I updated my code

Comment: that's what I meant, I just simplified the example :)